# Spring Couchbase Health Indicator

Tags: java, spring, couchbase, indicator, health-monitoring

I'm having trouble setting up a health indicator for my Spring project. Since version 1.4.0 Spring comes with its own CouchbaseHealthIndicator (see http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.4.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/health/CouchbaseHealthIndicator.html) but I cannot make it work. Other health indicators are working fine (disk space in this project, mail and db in other projects).

```
@ConditionalOnClass({ CouchbaseOperations.class, Bucket.class })
@ConditionalOnBean(CouchbaseOperations.class)
@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator("couchbase")
```

This are the conditions for the health indicator being initialized. The mentioned classes are on the classpath.
After the project is started, I let it print the beans it has in its application context - there is a bean 'CouchbaseTemplate', which implements the required CouchbaseOperations.

I also manually enabled the couchbase health check like this

```
management.health.couchbase.enabled = true
```

Still, it keeps checking disc space, no check for couchbase.

You can find my project on GitHub: https://github.com/Age15990/CouchbaseHI
Please feel free to download and try. If you have come across this problem before or you have an idea how to solve it I would be happy to read your answer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a bug that Patrick reported. It will be fixed as of `1.4.3` to be released in a few weeks now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a defect in `spring-boot-starter-actuator`. I filed a ticket for that [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7543).

A work-around could be to provide the configuration yourself:

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnClass({ CouchbaseOperations.class, Bucket.class })
//@ConditionalOnBean(CouchbaseOperations.class)
@ConditionalOnEnabledHealthIndicator("couchbase")
public class CouchbaseHealthConfig extends CompositeHealthIndicatorConfiguration<CouchbaseHealthIndicator, CouchbaseOperations>
{
    private final Map<String, CouchbaseOperations> couchbaseOperations;

    public CouchbaseHealthConfig(Map<String, CouchbaseOperations> couchbaseOperations)
    {
        this.couchbaseOperations = couchbaseOperations;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = "couchbaseHealthIndicator")
    public HealthIndicator couchbaseHealthIndicator()
    {
        return createHealthIndicator(this.couchbaseOperations);
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

The auto-configuration of the couchbase health indicator seems to be broken. It works for me when I comment-out `@ConditionalOnBean(CouchbaseOperations.class)` from the original configuration in `HealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class`.

This means `CouchbaseOperations.class` was not initialized properly before the auto-configuration took place.